# Issue with =IF() statements

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

Have a long list of numerical data. The sum of the numbers equal to 0, but the IF statement returns NO.
Any idea why that is?

```
=IF(SUM(values)=0, "YES","NO")
```

Comment: Check that it isn't a rounding issue: enter formula for sum of your values and press F9 to calculate the value - you may find it is a very small number e.g. 0.00000001. You can use the round() function in your stated formula to remove round-off errors.

Comment: Oh yes... And not only can it be rounding issues, it can be limitations of excel' math capabilities as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result !

Comment: Use "Evaluate Formula" (on the Ribbon, under Formulas) to see what the value of your SUM is. If it's close to zero, consider changing the formula to check for that (use ABS).

Comment: does `=IF(SUM(INT(values))=0, "YES","NO")` works?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the IF statement returning "NO" instead of "YES" could be due to the presence of zero-length strings in the numerical data. The ISBLANK() function in Excel returns "FALSE" for cells that appear to be empty but contain zero-length strings. This behavior can also occur when using the SUM() function. To work around this issue, you can use the LEN() function to check for zero-length strings and adjust the IF statement accordingly. Here's an example:

```
=IF(SUM(values)+SUM(IF(LEN(values)=0,0,1))=0, "YES","NO")
```

This formula adds the count of non-zero-length cells to the SUM() function to account for zero-length strings. If the sum of the values and the count of non-zero-length cells equals zero, the IF statement returns "YES", otherwise it returns "NO".